# Android place Relative Layout below Relative Layout programmatically

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

Hi I am having troubles trying to get this Relative Layout placed below another Relative Layout.  In my Activity I have a NavBar (RelativeLayout) that is aligned to the top of the activity.  I would like to place my TitleBar (RelativeLayout) below this programmatically.

Here is my onCreate method where I allocate both the NavBar and TitleBar and add them to my Activity.  The NavBar is correctly aligned at the top of the activity, however, the TitleBar is aligned with the top of the activity as well.  I'd like the top of the TitleBar to align with the bottom of the NavBar so it is placed below the NavBar.

```
    super.onCreate(bundle);

    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params;

    //navbar
    this.navBar = new BINavBar(context);
    relativeLayout.addView(this.navBar);

    params = (LayoutParams)this.navBar.getLayoutParams();
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    this.navBar.setLayoutParams(params);

    //titleBar
    this.titleBar = new BITitleBar(context);
    relativeLayout.addView(this.titleBar);

    params = (LayoutParams)this.titleBar.getLayoutParams();
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.BINavBar_layout);
    this.titleBar.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you are actually setting the id of the nav bar. Try the following:

```
super.onCreate(bundle);

Context context = getApplicationContext();
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params;

//navbar
this.navBar = new BINavBar(context);
relativeLayout.addView(this.navBar);

params = (LayoutParams)this.navBar.getLayoutParams();
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
this.navBar.setLayoutParams(params);
this.navBar.setId(R.id.BINavBar_layout); // this is the change

//titleBar
this.titleBar = new BITitleBar(context);
relativeLayout.addView(this.titleBar);

params = (LayoutParams)this.titleBar.getLayoutParams();
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, this.navBar.getId()); // this should use navBar's id
this.titleBar.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Note that you may need to set the id yourself. Are you sure that `R.id.BINavBar_layout` exists? If not, try using the following function: [View.generateViewId()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#generateViewId%28%29)

Comment: Yes, thank you that worked.  I found getId() in the documentation which I tried and it still didn't work.  I had to use in conjunction with setId as you mentioned. this.navBar.setId(R.id.BINavBar_layout); I had it set in XML resource, but it still required to be set programmatically.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad to have helped! If this answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to it on the left. Please see: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more info

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling the ID of the view you're creating isn't using the ID you're trying to use.  Try this:

```
//params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.BINavBar_layout);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, this.navBar.getId());
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for the response.  Along with getId() I had to setId() as mentioned by BVB. this.navBar.setId(R.id.BINavBar_layout);  Thanks all!